# Spark print result of Arrays or saveAsTextFile

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have been bogged down by this for some hours now... tried collect and mkString(") and still i am not able to print in console or save as text file.

```
scala> val au1 = sc.parallelize(List(("a",Array(1,2)),("b",Array(1,2))))
scala> val au2 = sc.parallelize(List(("a",Array(3)),("b",Array(2))))
scala> val au3 = au1.union(au2)
```

Result of the union is

```
Array[(String,Array[int])] = Array((a,Array(1,2)),(b,Array(1,2)),(a,Array(3)),(b,Array(2)))
```

All the print attempts are resulting in following when i do x(0) and x(1)

```
 Array[Int]) does not take parameters
```

Last attempt, performed following and it is resulting in index error

```
scala> val au4 = au3.map(x => (x._1, x._2._1._1, x._2._1._2))
<console>:33: error: value _1 is not a member of Array[Int]
         val au4 = au3.map(x => (x._1, x._2._1._1, x._2._1._2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`._1` or `._2` can be done in `tuples` and **not** in `arrays`

`("a",Array(1,2))` is a tuple so `._1` is `a` and `._2` is `Array(1,2)`

so if you want to get elements of an array you need to use `()` as `x._2(0)`

but `au2` arrays has only one element so `x._2(1)` will work for `au1` and **not** for `au2`. You can use `Option` or `Try` as below

```
val au4 = au3.map(x => (x._1, x._2(0), Try(x._2(1)) getOrElse(0)))
```

Comment: i was trying to follow `(E01,((Sophia,50000),Sebastian))` hence ._1 etc

Comment: Your question suggests the second parameter is an array. but your comments suggests its a tuple. I am confused :) please update which is correct.

Comment: i am confused between tuple and array... both the answers have cleared the confusion.

Comment: tuples are like arrays but you can store multiple datatypes in it but arrays can store only one datatype. I have explained the difference in extracting elements from tuples and arrays in my answer. :)

Comment: my understanding was totally opposite. Thats what happens when you live on coffee and don't get enough sleep.

Comment: that happens :) glad to have helped you clear your understanding.

Comment: Thanks, both the answers are great.

Answer (score 2):

The result of au3 is not `Array[(String,Array[int])]` , it is `RDD[(String,Array[int])]`
so this how you could do to write output in a file

```
au3.map( r => (r._1, r._2.map(_.toString).mkString(",")))
  .saveAsTextFile("data/result")
```

You need to map through the array and create a string from it so that it could be written in file as

```
(a,1:2)
(b,1:2)
(a,3)
(b,2)
```

You could write to file without brackets as below

```
au3.map( r => Row(r._1, r._2.map(_.toString).mkString(":")).mkString(","))
  .saveAsTextFile("data/result")
```

Output:

```
a,1:2
b,1:2
a,3
b,2
```

The value is comma `","` separated and array value are separated as `":"`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was looking at your solution for another problem and have a question now, what is `Row` in `au3.map( r => Row(r._1, r._2.map`

Comment: Row is collection of data in spark similar to tuple in scala, this represents a single row as in database row. This collection of row is known as dataframe

Comment: Hmmm, in my VM it isn't being picked as a valid syntax. Will look into it after work little more.

Comment: did you import org.apache.spark.sql.Row ??

Comment: No. I am new to BigData world, still learning a ton every day!

Comment: you need to import org.apache.spark.sql.Row to use it, Don't worry you will improve day by day slowly.